# What are the vcgencmd measure_clock 26 and 50?

Tags: hardware, raspbian-stretch, firmware, system-clock

There are 2 clock sources that are not officially (?) listed with a string id available to the `vcgencmd measure_clock` command.

```bsh
# for i in {0..255}; do vcgencmd measure_clock $i; done | grep -v "=0"

frequency(1)=400000000
frequency(9)=163683000
frequency(22)=47999000
frequency(26)=4800000
frequency(28)=299999000
frequency(29)=148500000
frequency(42)=300000000
frequency(43)=300000000
frequency(45)=1200000000
frequency(47)=200000000
frequency(50)=1920000

# for src in arm core h264 isp v3d uart pwm emmc pixel vec hdmi dpi ; do x=$(vcgencmd measure_clock $src ); echo -e "$src:\t$x"; done;

arm:    frequency(45)=1200000000
core:   frequency(1)=400000000
h264:   frequency(28)=300000000
isp:    frequency(42)=300000000
v3d:    frequency(43)=300000000
uart:   frequency(22)=48000000
pwm:    frequency(25)=0
emmc:   frequency(47)=200000000
pixel:  frequency(29)=148500000
vec:    frequency(10)=0
hdmi:   frequency(9)=163683000
dpi:    frequency(4)=0
```

There are (at least) 2 clocks here that are non-zero, `26` and `50`, but which do not have an official name.

**What do they represent?** (Are there others?)

Comment: they seem to correspond to `/sys/kernel/debug/clk/otp/clk_rate` and `/sys/kernel/debug/clk/tsens/clk_rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jaromanda's answer.

- clk **#26** = `otp` - is the One Time Programmable clock rate
- clk **#50** = `tsens` - is the temperature sensor clock rate

In the linux kernel file: [clk-bcm2835.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/29653ef5475124316b9284adb6cbfc97e9cae48f/drivers/clk/bcm/clk-bcm2835.c#L1955-L1964):

```c
    /*
     * Clock for the temperature sensor.
     * Generally run at 2Mhz, max 5Mhz.
     */
    [BCM2835_CLOCK_TSENS] = REGISTER_OSC_CLK(
        .name = "tsens",
        .ctl_reg = CM_TSENSCTL,
        .div_reg = CM_TSENSDIV,
        .int_bits = 5,
        .frac_bits = 0),
...
    /* One Time Programmable Memory clock.  Maximum 10Mhz. */
    [BCM2835_CLOCK_OTP] = REGISTER_OSC_CLK(
        .name = "otp",
        .ctl_reg = CM_OTPCTL,
        .div_reg = CM_OTPDIV,
        .int_bits = 4,
        .frac_bits = 0,
        .tcnt_mux = 6),
```

We can also find all clocks from the *sysfs* kernel debug path:

```bsh
#  sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/clk/clk_summary

   clock                         enable_cnt  prepare_cnt        rate   accuracy   phase
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 uart1_pclk                               0            0   125000000          0 0
 uart0_pclk                               0            0     3000000          0 0
 apb_pclk                                 0            0   126000000          0 0
 otg                                      0            0   480000000          0 0
 osc                                      7            7    19200000          0 0
    gp2                                   1            1       32768          0 0
    tsens                                 1            1     1920000          0 0
    vec                                   0            0    19200000          0 0
    otp                                   0            0     4800000          0 0
    timer                                 0            0     1000002          0 0
    pllh                                  4            4  1485000000          0 0
       pllh_pix_prediv                    1            1  1485000000          0 0
          pllh_pix                        0            0   148500000          0 0
       pllh_aux                           1            1     5800782          0 0
       pllh_rcal_prediv                   1            1     5800782          0 0
          pllh_rcal                       0            0      580078          0 0
    plld                                  3            3  2000000024          0 0
       plld_dsi1                          0            0     7812501          0 0
       plld_dsi0                          0            0     7812501          0 0
       plld_per                           3            3   500000006          0 0
          gp1                             1            1    25000000          0 0
          hsm                             0            0   163682866          0 0
          uart                            1            2    47999625          0 0
       plld_core                          2            2   500000006          0 0
          sdram                           0            0   166666668          0 0
    pllc                                  3            3  2000000024          0 0
       pllc_per                           1            1  1000000012          0 0
          emmc                            0            0   200000002          0 0
       pllc_core2                         0            0     7812501          0 0
       pllc_core1                         0            0     7812501          0 0
       pllc_core0                         2            2  1000000012          0 0
          vpu                             1            1   400000000          0 0
             aux_spi2                     0            0   400000000          0 0
             aux_spi1                     0            0   400000000          0 0
             aux_uart                     0            0   400000000          0 0
             peri_image                   0            0   400000000          0 0
    pllb                                  2            2  1200000000          0 0
       pllb_arm                           1            1   600000000          0 0
    plla                                  2            2  2000000024          0 0
       plla_ccp2                          0            0     7812501          0 0
       plla_dsi0                          0            0     7812501          0 0
       plla_per                           0            0     7812501          0 0
       plla_core                          1            1  1000000012          0 0
          h264                            0            0   250000003          0 0
          isp                             0            0   250000003          0 0
          v3d                             0            0   250000003          0 0
 dsi1p                                    0            0           0          0 0
 dsi0p                                    0            0           0          0 0
 dsi1e                                    0            0           0          0 0
 dsi0e                                    0            0           0          0 0
 cam1                                     0            0           0          0 0
 cam0                                     0            0           0          0 0
 dpi                                      0            0           0          0 0
 tec                                      0            0           0          0 0
 smi                                      0            0           0          0 0
 slim                                     0            0           0          0 0
 gp0                                      0            0           0          0 0
 dft                                      0            0           0          0 0
 aveo                                     0            0           0          0 0
 pcm                                      0            0           0          0 0
 pwm                                      0            0           0          0 0
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Thanks. I was never notified about this...